# I need help creating ListTile in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a book and I want to implement the chapters of the book in ListTile in Flutter:

But I can't fix it. I need help. My ListTile is like this:

```
class Item {
  final String name;
  Item({required this.name});
}

class Main_Audio_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item(name: "Chapter 1"),
    Item(name: "Chapter 2"),
    Item(name: "Chapter 3"), // and so on
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chapters'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
       itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items.toString()),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onTap: () {},
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update 1:

I want to create a book and I want to implement the chapters of the book in ListTile in Flutter:

```
class Main_Index_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  Main_Index_Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final items = List<String>.generate(115, (i) => "index $i");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Index Example'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index+1]),  <---here on this line I get the error.
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `title: Text(items[index].name),`

Comment: @Mardel I know thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with idk `Index` maybe btw it's solved now.

Code:

```
class Item {
  final String name;
  Item({required this.name});
}

class Main_Audio_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item(name: "Chapter 1"),
    Item(name: "Chapter 2"),
    Item(name: "Chater 3"), // and so on
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Chapters'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index].name),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
            onTap: () {},
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```